# Python mqtt client which tries to connect to broker when no internet

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I have somewhat unstable wifi network at home. I have pyhon code running on raspberry pi which tries to connect to "test.mosquitto.com" broker.

Below is the python code which I have written

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
bConnected = False

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, msg):
    print "Disonnected from broker"
    global bConnected
    bConnected = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, msg):
    print "Connected to broker"
    global bConnected
    bConnected = True

def worker_thread():
    """Creates mqtt client which check connection between pi and mqtt broker"""
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    global bConnected
    while not bConnected:
        try:
            print "Trying to connect broker"
            client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 5)
            client.loop_forever()
            time.sleep(5)

        except:
            bConnected = False
```

It works fine for me. 
Please let me know is there another efficient way to do this.(I guess there should be another way).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you restart your `worker_thread` when the client disconnects? Let's say your client is disconnected by a network error and `bConnected = False`, the thread will have already exited due to the first connection being successful and `bConnected = True`. Is there any other place you create another thread?

Comment: @Hicaro loop_forever() function does it for me.

Comment: As loop_forever documentaton says "This is a blocking form of the network loop and will not return until the client calls disconnect(). It automatically handles reconnecting"

Comment: @cgoma did you get the answer to this question? if yes, could you please share it. Thanks