# How to handle when MQTT client tries to connect without internet?

Tags: python, mqtt, iot, paho

I am using the paho mqtt library for python on an iot device. And for the most part the setup I have is working properly. However, I have found that if I try to connect when there is no internet connection, the scipt will throw a socket error (socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution) and because of it, it'll get stuck and not try to connect again.

I am trying to find out how to deal with this case, and I am wondering if you have any advice. [I am basing my code off of this example.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/mqtt_example/cloudiot_mqtt_example.py)

In summary, this is what I have for main function and connext/disconnect ones:

```
def on_connect(unused_client, unused_userdata, unused_flags, rc):
    """Callback for when a device connects."""
    print('on_connect', mqtt.connack_string(rc))
    print("connection time: ", datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    # After a successful connect, reset backoff time and stop backing off.
    global should_backoff
    global minimum_backoff_time
    should_backoff = False
    minimum_backoff_time = 1


def on_disconnect(unused_client, unused_userdata, rc):
    """Paho callback for when a device disconnects."""
    print('on_disconnect', error_str(rc))
    print("disconnection time: ", datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    # Since a disconnect occurred, the next loop iteration will wait with
    # exponential backoff.
    global should_backoff
    should_backoff = True

def main():

    # global JWT_EXPIRES_MINUTES
    global minimum_backoff_time

    jwt_iat = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    jwt_exp_mins = JWT_EXPIRES_MINUTES
    # Use gateway to connect to server
    client = get_client(
        project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id,
        private_key_file, algorithm, ca_certs, mqtt_bridge_hostname,
        mqtt_bridge_port)

    while True:
        client.loop()

        if should_backoff:
            # If backoff time is too large, give up.
            if minimum_backoff_time > MAXIMUM_BACKOFF_TIME:
                print('Exceeded maximum backoff time. Giving up.')
                break

            delay = minimum_backoff_time + random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000.0
            time.sleep(delay)
            minimum_backoff_time *= 2
            client.connect(mqtt_bridge_hostname, mqtt_bridge_port)

        seconds_since_issue = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - jwt_iat).seconds
        # print(f"seconds since issue: {seconds_since_issue}")
        if seconds_since_issue > 60 * jwt_exp_mins:
            print('Refreshing token after {}s'.format(seconds_since_issue))
            jwt_iat = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            client.loop()
            client.disconnect()
            # Wait a short time, so the cloud function has some buffer to react to the disconnection,
            # before reacting to the connection.
            time.sleep(5)
            client = get_client(
                project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id,
                private_key_file, algorithm, ca_certs, mqtt_bridge_hostname,
                mqtt_bridge_port)

        time.sleep(1)
```

When I googled for it, [I found this SO answer which looked promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41378490/python-mqtt-client-which-tries-to-connect-to-broker-when-no-internet). I have implemented it just around the client.loop() line after while True, but it doesn't work quite right, I believe it's because I am using client.loop() and not client.loop_forever().

I am writing the state of the connection (which I get from GCP logs) to a database and what I see is the following: Initially it connects as I would expect, but almost immediately I get a message of "deadline exceeded" and the status changes from "connect" to "publish" (but I am not publishing anything at the moment), shortly after I get a "disconnect" with the description "SUBSCRIBE: The connection was closed because the device did not acknowledge QoS 1 messages within the required time period.".

I am not sure what is the best way to implement this. Basically, I want to catch this socket error happening when there is no connection and continue to try until it won't be a problem. After that, I want it to continue working the same way as the code above. Does this make sense, or should I go about it some other way?

Comment: What line of code is throwing the error? Your post is not clear about that.

Comment: And why not just try and catch the error, and when caught, increment your backoff??

Comment: @JD Allen. Sorry, I guess I didn't explain it correctly. Technically, it is not giving me an error. The script seems to continue running, but it's not working properly. 

Basically, as I mentioned, it seems to connect but then after a bit I get the message that the connection was closed because it did not acknowledge qos 1 message. This never happened before. So while the script didn't close in error, it is not connecting.

Also, the last thing that happened was that it printed out a message from the "on_connect" function. It just closes connection later.

Comment: Also, I am trying to catch the error and then repeat until it will do it successfully, similar to the link I provided. But this problem I have right now is happening when internet connection is available and it should connect without an issue in the first place. At least it used to work, but I must have done something wrong. All I did was replicate what my second link in the OP shows, right after the while True. This seems to change the way my code originally worked, as it used to connect without issue.

Comment: You might want to have some sort of connection status flag to check before trying to publish.  Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36093078/mqtt-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-client-is-still-connected

Comment: I am going to look into this. For now I am catching the error as you suggested. I had to move around where the connection happened and had to catch it in more than one place so maybe not the cleanest. But I think it is working properly now. Thank you!